# Google WebFonts Loader - Top or bottom?

Tags: modernizr, webfonts

According to the HTML5 Boilerplate team (and many other authors, for sure), all JS on a given page should go at the bottom (right before the `</body>` tag) as far as this is possible, except for Modernizr due to the way it acts during page load.

Given that Google WebFonts Loader works, as far as I can tell, pretty much the same way as Modernizr (by doing `@font-face` feature-detection and adding classes to the `<html>` tag), I wonder if the same holds true for this script...

Should this go on the `<head>` or `<body>` tag? Does it matter all that much?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: as much as the pageload speed purists would love to tell you otherwise, the reality is that no, it doesn't actually matter that much. Put it at the top.

The only reason for putting JS includes at the foot of the page is for page loading performance reasons. If putting it at the top does not result in a noticeable performance drop, then it really doesn't matter. Particularly it's just the one or two scripts and you stick to having most of your scripts still at the bottom. The things is: for most sites, the difference it makes is pretty negligible.

I don't really know the answer as it applies specifically to Google Webfonts, as I haven't used that library (yet), but my advice is just stick it at the top with Modernizr, and be done with worrying about it.